# Redirect crontab output to email

Tags: linux, email, cron

It looks simple but how can I redirect output of this kind of crontab to my email?

```
00 06 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/myapp/testing.sh -e prod 1>> /var/log/CRONLOGS/testing_prod.log 2>&1
```

I've try to add MAILTO=myemail@email.com but without any results.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

The cron entry you have there is redirecting both `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to a file: `/var/log/CRONLOGS/testing_prod.log`.

The simplest method to do what you want would be to run `mailx` at the end of the cron job, using indirection to send that file:

```
00 06 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/myapp/testing.sh -e prod 1>> /var/log/CRONLOGS/testing_prod.log 2>&1; mailx -s "Cron output" me@example.org < /var/log/CRONLOGS/testing_prod.log
```

**However**: take note that your cron job is *appending* to the log file, so unless it's being purged of old entries (or rotated) regularly, you'll receive all previous output as well as new output. It would probably be best to create a small shell script to write to a temporary log, mail it, then append it to the mail log:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /home/user/myapp/testing.sh -e prod 1>> /tmp/testing_prod$$.log 2>&1
mailx -s "Cron output" me@example.org < /tmp/testing_prod$$.log
cat /tmp/testing_prod$$.log >> /var/log/CRONLOGS/testing_prod.log
rm /tmp/testing_prod$$.log
```

This has the benefit of making the `crontab` look tidier:

```
00 06 * * * /home/user/myapp/cronscript.sh
```

Comment: `tee` is a much better solution as it will still append to the log file and also only email out the new data without needing a temporary file.

Comment: It's _a_ solution. Personally I prefer to script it so that I can have a custom subject and mail recipient. The mail could also include diagnostic info, if required, along with the logs.

Comment: You can still use `tee` in your scripting as well rather then mucking with temporary files.

Comment: TIMTOWTDI. There's nothing wrong with temporary files, but sure, tee would also work in this instance. Either way I tend to prefer scripts so that the `crontab` isn't cluttered and unreadable.